# How to open teraterm SSH/Telnet connection from windows command prompt?

Tags: cmd, teraterm

I got a solution to open a teraterm COM connection and run a macro - 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe" /I /C=7 /BAUD=115200 /M="E:\old data\Desktop\TTL\RvR\test.ttl"

However, need help on arguments to be given to open a SSH/Telnet connection to a particular host from cmd using teraterm and run a macro.

Comment: Does the documentation help? https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/connect.html

Comment: ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/connect.html  link helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is 100 percent working code for telnet to a remote host ip
send username password and a command on remote machine.
If you want to send any argument x as variable inside u can use VAR %x and %x% as its value

contents of test.ttl file in local folder as follows
start copy from next line by chanimg ip username and password

```
connect 'IP:23'

pause 2

sendln 'Remoteusername'

pause 2

sendln 'Remotepassword'

pause 2

logopen 'C:\Users\nocbb\test.txt' 0 0

sendln 'command on remote host'

pause 3

sendln 'logout'

logclose

end
```

copy till above line
Save as all files and `test.ttl` and
run in dos command

run using command

```
C:\Users\nocbb>"C:\Program Files (x86)"\teraterm\ttermpro /M=C:\Users\nocbb\test.ttl /nossh
```

Note Change the path as per installation folder of Teraterm in
ur installation of teraterm folder.